# Expected 2D array, got scalar array instead, output being thrown when predicting polynomial regression

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, machine-learning, polynomial-math

Output:

- Expected 2D array, got scalar array instead:
  `array=6.5`.

Reshape your data either using `array.reshape(-1, 1)` if your data has a single feature or `array.reshape(1, -1)` if it contains a single sample.

````
# Data Preprocessing

# Importing the libraries
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

# Importing the dataset
dataset = pd.read_csv('Position_Salaries.csv')
X = dataset.iloc[:, 1:2].values # 1:2 is to consider X as a matrix
y = dataset.iloc[:, 2].values

# Fitting Linear Regression to the dataset
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
lin_reg = LinearRegression()
lin_reg.fit(X,y)

# Fitting Polynomial Regression in the dataset
from sklearn.preprocessing import PolynomialFeatures
poly_reg = PolynomialFeatures(degree = 4)
X_poly = poly_reg.fit_transform(X)
lin_reg_2 = LinearRegression()
lin_reg_2.fit(X_poly, y)

# Visualising the Linear Regression Results
plt.scatter(X,y, color = 'red')
plt.plot(X, lin_reg.predict(X), color = 'blue')
plt.title('Truth or Bluff (linear Regression)')
plt.xlabel(' Position Level ')
plt.ylabel('Salary')
plt.show()

# Visualising the Polynomial Regression Results 
X_grid = np.arange(min(X), max(X), 0.1)
X_grid = X_grid.reshape((len(X_grid),1))
plt.scatter(X,y, color = 'red')
plt.plot(X, lin_reg_2.predict(poly_reg.fit_transform(X)), color = 'blue')
plt.title('Truth or Bluff (Polynomial Regression)')
plt.xlabel(' Position Level ')
plt.ylabel('Salary')
plt.show()


# Predicting a new result with Linear Regression
lin_reg.predict(6.5)    

# Predicting a new result with Polynomial Regression
lin_reg_2.predict(poly_reg.fit_transform(6.5)) ```
````

Comment: Maybe try `lin_reg.predict(np.array([6.5])) ` ?

Comment: What's `'Position_Salaries.csv'`? Can you post a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example ?

Comment: Thank you for your Answers ` lin_reg.predict([[6.5]])` this worked!  @thomask